# Why is this program slower with more threads?

Tags: multithreading, performance, rust

My program takes twice as long to execute when run with two threads, compared to when running with just one thread.

I've created [a minimal example program with the same problem](https://github.com/avl/scoped_pool_perf_problem) using [`scoped-pool`](https://crates.io/crates/scoped-pool):

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate scoped_pool;
extern crate test;

use scoped_pool::Pool;
use test::Bencher;

/// This is a minimized program exhibiting a performance problem
/// Why is this program twice as fast, when the number of threads is set to 1 instead of 2?
#[bench]
pub fn test_bench_alt(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let parallellism = 1;
    let data_size = 500_000;

    let mut pool = Pool::new(parallellism);

    {
        let mut data = Vec::new();
        for _ in 0..data_size {
            data.push(0);
        }

        let mut output_data = Vec::<Vec<i32>>::new();
        for _ in 0..parallellism {
            let mut t = Vec::<i32>::with_capacity(data_size / parallellism);
            output_data.push(t);
        }
        b.iter(move || {
            for i in 0..parallellism {
                output_data[i].clear();
            }
            {
                let mut output_data_ref = &mut output_data;
                let data_ref = &data;
                pool.scoped(move |scope| {
                    for (idx, output_data_bucket) in output_data_ref.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                        scope.execute(move || {
                            for item in &data_ref[(idx * (data_size / parallellism))
                                                      ..((idx + 1) * (data_size / parallellism))]
                            {
                                //Yes, this is a logic bug when parallellism does not evenely divide data_size. I could use "chunks" to avoid this, but I wanted to keep this simple for this analysis.
                                output_data_bucket.push(*item);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            let mut output_data_ref = &mut output_data;
            pool.scoped(move |scope| {
                for sub in output_data_ref.iter_mut() {
                    scope.execute(move || {
                        for sublot in sub {
                            assert!(*sublot != 42);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This is a program which takes an input vector, processes part of this vector in each thread, aggregates output in one vector per thread, then processes the resulting vectors. The real program is more complex, but this minimized program still exhibits the performance issue, even though it does nothing of value.

Running cargo bench:

With one thread:

```
test test_bench_alt ... bench:     781,105 ns/iter (+/- 1,103)
```

With two threads:

```
test test_bench_alt ... bench:   1,537,465 ns/iter (+/- 154,499)
```

Why is the program slower when run with two threads? And what could be done to make it faster?

Update:

The following highly optimized C++-program does approximately the same job, and scales (on my machine) up to 19 threads, proving that the workload can in fact be parallellized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <sched.h>
#include <atomic>



#define PAR 1
#define DATASIZE 524288

std::vector<std::vector<int>> output;
std::vector<int> input;


int run_job1(int task) {

    int l = DATASIZE/PAR;
    int off = task*(DATASIZE/PAR);
    auto temp = &output[task][0];
    auto ip = &input[off];
    for(int i=0;i<l;++i){
        *temp=*ip;//+off;
        temp+=1;
        ip+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int run_job2(int task) {
    auto& temp = output[task];
    auto temp_p = &output[task][0];
    auto temp_p2 = temp_p + DATASIZE/PAR;
    int expected = task*(DATASIZE/PAR);
    while(temp_p!=temp_p2) {
        if (*temp_p!=expected)
            printf("Woha!\n");
        temp_p+=1;
        expected+=1;
    }
    return 0;
}

std::atomic_int valsync=0;
std::atomic_int valdone=0;

void* threadfunc(void* p) {
    int i = (int)(long)p;
    cpu_set_t set;
    CPU_ZERO(&set);
    CPU_SET(i, &set);
        sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(set),&set);

    int expect=1;
    while(true) {
        while(valsync.load()!=expect) {
        }
        expect+=1;        
        run_job1(i);
        valdone+=1;

        while(valsync.load()!=expect) {
        }
        expect+=1;        
        run_job2(i);    
        valdone+=1;
    }

}

int main() {

    for(int i=0;i<DATASIZE;++i) {
        input.push_back(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<PAR;++i) {
        std::vector<int> t;
        for(int j=0;j<DATASIZE/PAR;++j)
            t.push_back(0);
        output.push_back(t);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < PAR ; ++i)
    {
        pthread_t thread_id;
        if(pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, threadfunc, (void*)i)) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;

        }   
    }
    for(int run=0;run<20;++run)
    {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for(int j=0;j<1000;++j) {

            std::atomic_fetch_add(&valsync,1);
            while(true)  {
                int expected=PAR;
                if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&valdone,&expected,0))
                    break;

            }


            std::atomic_fetch_add(&valsync,1);
            while(true)  {
                int expected=PAR;
                if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&valdone,&expected,0))
                    break;
            }
        }
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2= std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 
        auto delta  = t2-t1;

        std::cout<<"Time: "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(delta).count()/1000<<" ns per iter \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/)?

Comment: Yes, I looked at it quickly. However, I need detailed control over which calculations run in parallel and which don't, to be able to flow data between different calculation steps without having to use mutexes (which I don't want to use because I want 100% determinism).

Comment: I tried rayon now, using it as a scoped threadpool. It's slightly slower than scoped_pool.

Comment: Are you running your program with `--release` flags?

Comment: @hellow `cargo bench` implies release.

Comment: Can not reproduce. `PARALLELISM=1 cargo +nightly bench` -> `1,419,959 ns/iter (+/- 188,210)`; `PARALLELISM=2 cargo +nightly bench` -> `1,397,151 ns/iter (+/- 48,459)`.

Comment: Any idea why you don't see more speedup? I'd almost expected a 2x speedup for two threads. Are you on a machine with hyperthreading? I am, maybe the slowdown occurs if both threads are run on the same core?

Comment: @avl_sweden How many cores do you have? And since I assume this is running on nightly, what happens if you update your nightly build?

Comment: I have 10 cores (Intel i9 7900X CPU). I'm running latest nightly.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to comment on what is wrong with my question? Maybe I can learn something?

Comment: I've now tried rewriting the program in C++ (oh how I don't miss the days of C++). I get more or less linear speedup up to 4 threads (140000 ns / iter), which seems reasonable since the thing should be memory-bandwidth-limited, and I have 4 memory controllers in my CPU.

Comment: So there's something fishy here, and I am going to find out what it is :-)

Comment: I meant "4 channels on my memory controller", not "4 memory controllers".

Comment: *rewriting the program in C++* — post that MCVE as well, that way we can more easily compare the two and highlight differences.

Comment: It's just that I have even more reason to be ashamed of my C++ than my Rust-code. But I will try and swallow my pride :-) . Will post code when I am back at the office.

Comment: I got the C++ program to 100000 ns/iteration with 8 threads, using a home-rolled busy-waiting thread-pool-implementation. Code is coming.

Comment: I've added the C++-program now. It is quite terrible, just a proof o concept, but shows (unless I made some terrible error) that the work-load I have (albeit very artificial) can in fact be parallelized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching the issue extensively and with lots of inspiration from the excellent answer by E_net4, I found the exact cause for the bad scaling of my original program.

We have to consider two separate issues here:

1. Why is the program so slow?
2. Why doesn't it scale to more than 1 CPU?

The answer to question 1 has been answered in impressive detail and with good precision by E_net4. The answer to question 2 is [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) / cache-line thrashing for the `output_data` vector.

When modern multi-core CPUs access main memory, they store data that they access from memory in their own dedicated cache. Subsequent requests to the same memory can be served from the fast cache instead of from the relatively slow main memory.

What happens if one core writes to memory that has been cached by another core? Whenever this happens, all cached copies in all cores must be updated or removed. This is implemented by keeping track of the state of each stored cache-line, using something like the [MOESI-protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol). For each cache line, the CPU keeps track of whether or not it is the sole owner.

Each cache is typically 64 bytes. The cache-line is, in its entirety, owned by one core. Now consider the bytes holding the output_data vector in the program in the question. Each `Vec` is 8*3 bytes (on a 64 bit machine) = 24 bytes. This means that the first two output vectors are probably stored in the same cache line.

Whenever `Vec::push` is executed, the `len` field of the `Vec` is incremented. This is a write, and thus requires that the cache-line is owned by the executing core. There will be some signaling between the cores, and the cache line will be transferred to the executing core. Consider that the other core is going to be executing `Vec::push` very soon as well. When this happens, the cache line is migrated back to the other core. The cache-line ownership is ping-ponging between the cores.

One way to fix this problem is to introduce padding between the individual `Vec` elements in the `output_data` vector, like this:

```
#[bench]
pub fn test_bench_alt(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let parallellism = 4;
    let data_size = 500_000;

    let mut pool = Pool::new(parallellism);

    struct Filler {
        odata: Vec<i32>,
        padding: [u8; 64],
    }

    {
        let mut data = Vec::new();
        for _ in 0..data_size {
            data.push(0);
        }

        let mut output_data = Vec::<Filler>::new();
        for _ in 0..parallellism {
            let mut t = Vec::<i32>::with_capacity(data_size / parallellism);
            output_data.push(Filler {
                odata: t,
                padding: [0; 64],
            });
        }
        b.iter(move || {
            for i in 0..parallellism {
                output_data[i].odata.clear();
            }
            {
                let mut output_data_ref = &mut output_data;
                let data_ref = &data;
                pool.scoped(move |scope| {
                    for (idx, output_data_bucket) in output_data_ref.iter_mut().enumerate() {
                        scope.execute(move || {
                            for item in &data_ref[(idx * (data_size / parallellism))
                                                      ..((idx + 1) * (data_size / parallellism))]
                            {
                                //Yes, this is a logic bug when parallellism does not evenely divide data_size. I could use "chunks" to avoid this, but I wanted to keep this simple for this analysis.
                                output_data_bucket.odata.push(*item);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            pool.scoped(|scope| {
                for sub in &output_data {
                    scope.execute(move || {
                        for sublot in &sub.odata {
                            assert!(*sublot != 42);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Parallelism = 1:

```
test test_bench_alt  ... bench:     729,826 ns/iter (+/- 16,718)
```

Parallelism = 2:

```
test test_bench_alt  ... bench:     374,167 ns/iter (+/- 9,933)
```

Parallelism = 4:

```
test test_bench_alt  ... bench:     206,906 ns/iter (+/- 10,559)
```

Note that E_net4's program is still much more efficient by using iterators and `collect` in a better way to avoid bounds checks, and it avoids the bad implications of false sharing by building the vector as a temporary and then assigning it only once per iteration to the `output_data` element, instead of constantly updating the `output_data` element.

Answer (score 7):

The main problem is that this benchmark is close to meaningless. Assigning and comparing numbers are not computationally intensive operations, meaning that there is hardly any value in parallelizing these operations. As well shown in those measurements, adding more threads only crippled performance.

The greatest bottleneck, surprisingly, might be in other trivial instructions emerging from constructing the output vectors, which could be avoided with iterators. Most interactions with vectors rely on the index operator `[]` to iterate a collection, which is unconventional and unadvised. Here is an improved version of the same benchmark. The changes sum up to the following:

- Initializing a vector with a specific element can be done with the `vec` macro: `vec![0; data_size]`.
- One can also use iterators to build the N initial vectors. An empty vector created with `Vec::new` does not allocate heap memory, so this is mostly fine.
- When assigning jobs to each worker, the input memory chunks and output vectors can just be zipped together. Iteration will automatically occur for both chunks, with much less bounds checking required. Also because of `chunks`, the last worker will not attempt to access out of bounds if it was given a smaller slice.
- The work of each thread can also be made and collected into a new vector with iterators, rather than producing a loop that pushes new values to an existing mutable vector on each step. The compiler can avoid many redundant checks with this approach.
- Lastly, the second part of the benchmark does not need mutable access to the "processed" content.

```rust
#[bench]
pub fn test_bench_alt(b: &mut Bencher) {
    let parallellism = 1;
    let data_size = 500_000;

    let pool = Pool::new(parallellism);

    {
        let data = vec![0; data_size];

        let mut output_data: Vec<_> = (0..parallellism).map(|_| Vec::new()).collect();

        b.iter(move || {
            for vec in &mut output_data {
                vec.clear();
            }

            {
                let data_ref = &data;
                pool.scoped(|scope| {
                    for (output_data_bucket, input_data_chunk) in (&mut output_data)
                        .into_iter()
                        .zip(data_ref.chunks(data_size / parallellism))
                    {
                        scope.execute(move || {
                            *output_data_bucket = input_data_chunk.into_iter().cloned().collect();
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
            pool.scoped(|scope| {
                for sub in &output_data {
                    scope.execute(move || {
                        for sublot in sub {
                            assert_ne!(*sublot, 42);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Before:**

```
test test_bench_alt ... bench:   1,352,071 ns/iter (+/- 516,762)
```

**After:**

```
test test_bench_alt ... bench:     533,573 ns/iter (+/- 213,486)
```

These numbers might only be slightly better with a few more threads, althoug with a higher variance. For parallellism = 2:

```
test test_bench_alt ... bench:     314,662 ns/iter (+/- 340,636)
```

If you bring a computationally intensive algorithm to the equation, then you can try again with these ideas in mind.

Comment: Yeah, I know the benchmark is meaningless. It is a reduction of an actual program. Thanks for all your work! However, I worry that, in your program the compiler has beeb able to statically eliminate much of the code. 500000 iterations in 488ns seems too good to be true.

Comment: Unfortunately I kind of need the output vectors for different threads to be separate, in the real program the amount of output from each iteration varies.

Comment: You seem to know your stuff. How did you determine that boundschecking was dominating? And are you saying that simple operations can't be parallelized? Why not? Memory bandwidth limitation?

Comment: But wait a minute, there should be very little boundschecking in the original program. All the main work is done with iterators! Is it in Vec::push?

Comment: @avl_sweden Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the benchmark with that information. If we stick to one vector per worker, the final measurements become more "realistic". The main points that I wish to portray still stand: (1) use the iterator API whenever possible, since it's more idiomatic and produces better machine code; (2) and make sure that your algorithm can indeed benefit from parallelism. :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I definitely did learn something from your rewrite of my program! As I posted above in the question, I have now written a very optimized (almost cheating) C++-version of the problem, and it exhibits good parallelism up to the machine core number. This tells me that the problem can in fact be parallelized. So the 'bad' scaling in the rust-code can probably be worked around somehow.

Comment: My guess right now is that it all has to do with whether or not the first part of the workload gets to run on the same core as the second part, and if it doesn't there is cache-thrashing in the L2-cache as cores have to steal cache-lines from each other.